# Generate sequential numbers on a join

Tags: postgresql

For each right-side row in a JOIN I'd like to create a sequential number, starting from 1 (or 0) for each left-side row.

Example:

```
create table persons (person_id int, person_name text);
create table places (place_id int, person_id int, place_name text);
insert into persons values (10, 'Aulus Agerius'), (20, 'Numerius Negidius');
insert into places values (10, 10, 'Anytown'), (20, 10, 'Timbuktu'), (30, 20, 'Podunk');
```

```
select person_name, place_name
from persons join places using (person_id)
order by person_id, place_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0rLDmRt_)

Desired result:

| person_name | place_name | place_seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aulus Agerius | Anytown | 1 |
| Aulus Agerius | Timbuktu | 2 |
| Numerius Negidius | Podunk | 1 |

So for example a 2 in `place_seq` would mean "this is the 2nd place found for this person".

How to create the `place_seq` column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)) window function as follows (the code below is shown on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vn51Hw5M) - based on your own fiddle +1 for that!):

```
SELECT 
  person_id,
  place_id,
  person_name, 
  place_name, 
  ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY place_id) AS rn
FROM persons 
  JOIN places using (person_id)
ORDER BY person_id, place_id;
```

This is based on the assumption that `person_id` & `place_id` are at least `UNIQUE` or (better) the `PRIMARY KEY`s of their respective tables. Conceivably, two people could have the same name - I've known two sets of three people (indepedent - not the same family) with the same name. As for places, duplicates are even more common.

Result:

```
person_name       place_name    rn
Aulus Agerius        Anytown     1
Aulus Agerius       Timbuktu     2
Numerius Negidius     Podunk     1
```

In order to be guaranteed to obtain consistent results over different runs, a deterministic `ORDER BY` clause in the window function is necessary. In general, an SQL statement should contain an `ORDER BY`, as should window functions, if we desire results in deterministic order.

For window functions, see also [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS). These functions are **very** powerful and will repay any effort spent learning them many times over. There are articles all over the web about them - I would urge you to have a look around and practice until you have have (some degree of) mastery of them.

As a first port of call, I **highly** recommend Bruce Momjian's YouTube presentation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO1WnmJs9RI) (slides [here](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/window.pdf)). Bruce Momjian is VP and "Postgres Evangelist" for [EnterpriseDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/) - the world's premier PostgreSQL company. He's also an excellent speaker and explains PostgreSQL functionality **very** well!